# How to Click button has no id

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner. I'm trying to click button below on a webpage :

```
<span class="action-delete" onclick=";return false;"> Delete </span>
```

I tried code below but didn't work

```
document.getElementsByClassName('action-delete').click()
```

I'm using greasemonkey & firefox

Thanks in advance

Screenshot below
[image]

Comment: And that's not a button, by the way :) it's a `<span>`

Comment: It is a button, when clicked, a message box pops up. It is only the code it has, as attached screenshot above

Comment: If it's a <span> that's styled to look like a button, then it's a button; it makes no difference to the answer to the question. Some people are just downright unfriendly. Anyway I posted the answer below.

Comment: thank you very much, i appreciate you taking your time and helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "s" in `getElementsByClassName` indicates that function returns a list. Assuming there's only one element with that class name, you can do:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('action-delete')[0].click()
```

Comment: @ValeriaKaya - It's 2013, it's time to start using [`document.querySelector(".action-delete").click()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
var trigger = document.getElementsByClassName("action-delete");

for (var i = 0, len = trigger.length; i < len; ++i) {
    trigger[i].addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        alert(e.target.innerHTML);

    }, false);
}

<span class="action-delete">Click me</span>
<span class="action-delete">Hello World</span>
<span class="action-delete">Nice to meet you</span>
```

here is a simple demo http://jsfiddle.net/6vs5m/